# How to apply drawtext and watermark at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg

drawtext cmd:

```
ffmpeg -ss 100 -t 5 -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text=HELLO:fontsize=60" output_1.mpeg
```

watermark cmd:

```
ffmpeg -ss 100 -t 5 -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output_2.mpeg
```

but what if I want to apply these two cmd at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both filters in the same `vf` filterchain, separated by commas.

`ffmpeg -ss 100 -t 5 -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10,drawtext=text=HELLO:fontsize=60:x=100:y=100" output_2.mpeg`